# Android Border Less Button Pressed State Background Color

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button

How can we change the background colour of a Border less button when the button is pressed.

I used this:

```
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/btn_skip"
```

Where my button Displays a label "SKIP" as defined in my "strings.xml".

Now When I test this it is Good Except It shows default "Blue" Colour when in Pressed State.
I want it to match it with other elements of my My UI theme that are "Orange" "#FF8800"

Any Ideas?

Thankx in advance...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Nimish-Choudhary ...! I followed your advice. and I have explained it further for clarity to all having same question as me as a beginner.

Create an xml with name say *"btntransparent.xml"*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true">

<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/pressed"/>
<item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@color/defaultColor"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@color/defaultColor"/>

</selector>
```

Next add the colors "pressed" and "defaultColor" to another xml say *"colors.xml"*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed">#CCFF8800</color>
    <color name="defaultColor">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

Here *"#CCFF8800"* is my pressed state *Translucent Orange* and *"#00000000"* is the *100% Transparent Black* (;-) thats invisible). You can find more about color codes at [Color| Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Now put the *"colors.xml"* in *values* Folder and *"btntransparent.xml"* in *drawable* Folder.

Now the last step is to voila use it in the button as

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/id_btn_skip"
            android:background="@drawable/transparentbtn"
            android:onClick="skipToMain"
            android:text="@string/btn_skip" />
```

And thats should do the job...!

Take care.
regards,
raisedadead

Comment: This approach will not work with Lollipop so you need to create a different background file for SDK >= 21 with the ripple effect and one for previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

instead of using ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground you can create a xml in drawable in folder with following content.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true">

<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/orange"/>
<item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@color/default"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@color/default"/>

</selector>
```

Updated:
so you save this files as : btn_drawable.xml  in drawable folder.

Simply replace  *?android:attr/selectableItemBackground*
with *@drawable/btn_drawable.xml*

Comment: Hey @nimish-choudhry Thanks for the update. Could you also tell me how to reference the above xml.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you could do is add new resource in @drawable for example my_ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:color="#FF8800">
</ripple>
```

Then simply set this as your background.

Answer (score -2):

In your theme add the following:

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">#FF8800</item>
```

to override the default blue.